# Design Pattern - Complex MultiObject Versioning w/Out-of-Sequence awareness

Tags: design-patterns

Here's the deal/challenge,

We have to keep track of information and it's linear changes.  We also have to keep track of changes that are out-of-sequence.  For example A happened then B happened.  Sometime later, we learn of C which actually happened before B.  Along with this challenge, we have many objects that have to be versioned that tie to each other.  If it were a single table/object that needed to be versioned...no big deal.  But, with multiple objects, now we get into more complex linking.  And, to throw in the concept of out-of-sequence events just complicates things.

When checking in code, you can't do out-of-sequence.  Stuff happens and then you fix/improve it.  However, in some systems you don't get all of the information at the time of the event or in a linear order.  Yet, you still have to calculate the real-world event time line even though it was different from the time line you received the information.

Short example of hierarchy: (each object has to be versioned)

1. Policy
2. Transaction (Date of the real-world change)
3. Coverage(s)
4. Location(s)
5. Coverage(s)
6. Vehicle(s)
7. Yada yada yada

From a viewpoint, if I need to get access to the current policy, I should see everything as it is now.  However, if I need to see what was changed as part of a transaction 3 weeks ago, I have to be able to see what it was before...what exactly was changed...then what it was after the change.

I had written up a pattern to try and address all of this while also trying to store only the information that changed (not duplicating the entire stack every time the version changed - which I've seen as a common practice when trying to address this issue).  I did look around the web and am novicely familiar with all the GoF patterns and a few more.  Still, either I'm missing the boat and going too complex or i'm just one of the infrequent people that have to deal with this kind of situation.

I'll post the pattern I worked up as soon as I can.  First, your ideas & wisdom.  If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ended up being 2 primary strategies to accomplish this with the core tradeoffs being either space or complexity.  For trading off with space, you copy full stacks of data and version them.  For trading off complexity, you manage a light key/pointer system that is versioned.

To keep things simple, we implemented trading off for space.

There are 5 core keys needed.  The primary ID, a LinearInstanceID, LinearPreviousID, NonLinearInstanceID, and NonLinearPreviousID.

1. ID = just as you expect, a unique identifier for the object type
2. NonLinearInstanceID = the first Id of the first instance ever
   created across all time
3. LinearInstanceID = the first Id of the first instance on a specific
   linear timeline
4. NonLinearPreviousID = the Id of the object to which it took the
   place of
5. LinearPreviousID = the Id of the change directly before it (ie.
   linked list)

The last piece to the puzzle is gating the workflow to decide when a new version is required of the whole attached object stack.  Usually this is easy since you have a natural business level transaction.

**Events**

-- all events: create new unique primary ids

1st Version:

1. set the LinearInstanceId & NonLinearInstanceId = ID
2. leave both previous id's null

New Version (normal linear):

1. copy the last versions of the objects
2. make sure LinearInstanceId & NonLinearInstanceId stays the same as
   they were
3. point LinearPreviousId to the id of the version before it
4. NonLinearPreviousId stays null

New Version (unusual non-linear):

1. get all of the objects on the current newest timeline and copy them
2. point the NonLinearPreviousId to the id on the timeline from which
   they were copied from
3. update LinearInstanceId to the new first copy's id
4. make sure NonLinearInstanceId stays the same
5. insert new version, relink LinearPreviousId chain (linked list)

**Benefits**

I know this seems like a lot of linking, but here are some of the benefits:

*Easily navigate to these areas on the current timeline or across all timelines*

- Original or Current Version
- Previous or Next Version
- List of Versions
- Keep All Versions of each object (works fine in a traditional RDBMS)
- Can use simple methods to detect changes between versions since all versions are kept and can easily navigate back/forth

I hope this helps anyone who is the same situation.  If you have any questions/comments, feel free to let me know.  If a visual aid would help, just let me know.